# java.lang.NullPointerException: null Spring API Rest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I am triying to make a simple rest service with Spring and Lombok but I have this problem: "NullPointerException", may you help me please?, belive me, I have tried everithing for insert but always is NullPointerException, here is my source

Entity class Book

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
```

}

BookRepository Interface

```
public interface BookRepository {

List<Book> findAll(); 
void save(Book book);
Book findOne(int id);
void delate(Book book);
void insert(Book book);
```

}

BookRepositoyImpl

```
@Repository
public class BookRepositoryImpl implements BookRepository{

    EntityManager em;

    BookRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em){
        this.em=em;
    }


    @Override
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Book> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Book.class);

        Root<Book> root =criteriaQuery.from(Book.class);

        criteriaQuery
            .select(root);
        TypedQuery<Book> query= em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Book book) {
    em.merge(book); 

    }

    @Override
    public Book findOne(int id) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Book> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Book.class);

        Root<Book> root =criteriaQuery.from(Book.class);
        Predicate IDPredicate =criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Book_.ID), id);

        criteriaQuery
        .select(root)
        .where(IDPredicate);
    TypedQuery<Book> query= em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void delate(Book book) {
        em.remove(book);

    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Book book) {

        em.persist(book);
    }


}
```

BookService

```
   @Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookServices {

    private BookRepository bokRepository;

    public List <Book> retribeBook(String user){
        return bokRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void DeleteBook(int id) {
        Book book=bokRepository.findOne(id);
        bokRepository.delate(book);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void UpdateBook(int id, String title) {
        Book book= bokRepository.findOne(id);
         book.setTitle(title);
         bokRepository.save(book);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void insert(Book book) {
        bokRepository.insert(book);

    }

    public Book findId(int id) {
        return bokRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

TestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    private BookServices bookServices;


    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> retrieveStudent(@RequestParam final String title) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookServices.retribeBook(title));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateBook(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String title ){

        bookServices.UpdateBook(id, title);

        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,path ="/Insert")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> Insert(@RequestBody Book book){

        bookServices.insert(book);

        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();       
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> DeleteBook(@RequestParam int id){
        bookServices.DeleteBook(id);
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }   
}
```

When I send a JSON with POSTMAN here is this message on the console

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at mx.stuteach.controller.TestController.Insert(TestController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

[image]

Comment: that is so much code, please provide the essential and important parts of the code.

Comment: Note that if you're using Spring Data, you should usually not implement your repository interface _at all_. Just use `BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long>` and delete your implementation.

Comment: Do you have an example with crud repository?, I have found too many using HTML, but nothing with JSON and Postman or SoapUI.

Comment: Make your `BookRepository` extend `CrudRepository`. Delete your Impl. Everything else should Just Work.

Comment: where are the autowire's?? ;) (lombok doesn't take care of that afaik)